# Matlab r2014b get info which tab is active in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabs

I have a code in the new Matlab R2014b version with tabs in a GUI:

```
hTabGroup = uitabgroup('units','pixels','position',[22 245 900 435])`   
tabs(1) = uitab(hTabGroup, 'title','Curve 1'); 
tabs(2) = uitab(hTabGroup, 'title','Curve 2');
```

How could I ask in the code which tab is active in the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`SelectedTab` property of the uitabgroup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitabgroup-properties.html):

> `SelectedTab` — Currently selected tab uitab object This property is
>   read only.
>
> Currently selected tab, specified as a uitab object.
>
> Use this property to determine the currently selected uitab within a
>   uitabgroup. You can also use this property to initialize the GUI with
>   a default uitab selection.
>
> The default value of the `SelectedTab` property is the first uitab that
>   you add to the uitabgroup.

Pulling the title, using your sample code and 'Curve 2' selected:

```
hTabGroup = uitabgroup('units','pixels','position',[22 245 900 435]);
tabs(1) = uitab(hTabGroup, 'title','Curve 1'); 
tabs(2) = uitab(hTabGroup, 'title','Curve 2'); 
mytab = hTabGroup.SelectedTab.Title
```

---

```
mytab =

Curve 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the property I was looking for!